# Can I improve the performance of this JSON conversion in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that resembles the following
(the following code creates a table called #Temp. This has 160,000 rows which is roughly the same number of rows I am working with in my real dataset but there are more columns in the real dataset):

```
/* Create dummy employees*/

;WITH employeeNumbers
AS ( SELECT 1 AS employeeId
     UNION ALL
     SELECT employeeNumbers.employeeId + 1
     FROM   employeeNumbers
     WHERE  employeeNumbers.employeeId < 16000 )
SELECT *
INTO   #employeeId
FROM   employeeNumbers
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 16000 )


/*Create saleItems*/
CREATE TABLE #SalesItems
    (
        category VARCHAR(100)
      , subCategory VARCHAR(100)
      , productName VARCHAR(1000)
    )
INSERT INTO #SalesItems ( category
                        , subCategory
                        , productName )
VALUES ( 'Furniture', 'Bookcases', 'Bush Somerset Collection Bookcase' )
     , ( 'Furniture', 'Chairs', 'Hon Deluxe Fabric Upholstered Stacking Chairs, Rounded Back' )
     , ( 'Office Supplies', 'Labels', 'Self-Adhesive Address Labels for Typewriters by Universal' )
     , ( 'Furniture', 'Tables', 'Bretford CR4500 Series Slim Rectangular Table' )
     , ( 'Office Supplies', 'Storage', 'Eldon Fold n Roll Cart System' )
     , ( 'Furniture', 'Furnishings', 'Eldon Expressions Wood and Plastic Desk Accessories, Cherry Wood' )
     , ( 'Office Supplies', 'Art', 'Newell 322' )
     , ( 'Technology', 'Phones', 'Mitel 5320 IP Phone VoIP phone' )
     , ( 'Office Supplies', 'Binders', 'DXL Angle-View Binders with Locking Rings by Samsill' )
     , ( 'Technology', 'Phones', 'Samsung Galaxy S8' )

-- Create some random sales figures between 10 and 100
SELECT employeeId
     , category
     , subCategory
     , productName
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Jul 2017]
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Aug 2017]
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Sep 2017]
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Oct 2017]
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Nov 2017]
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(13, 2), 10 + ( 100 - 10 ) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) [Dec 2017]
INTO   #Temp
FROM   #employeeId
JOIN   #SalesItems ON 1 = 1

CREATE INDEX empId
    ON #Temp ( employeeId )

SELECT *
FROM   #Temp
```

What I am doing is converting these results to a single json string for every employee id in the table. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.employeeId
              , (   SELECT y.category
                         , y.subCategory
                         , y.productName
                         , [Jul 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Jul 2017'
                         , [Aug 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Aug 2017'
                         , [Sep 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Sep 2017'
                         , [Oct 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Oct 2017'
                         , [Nov 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Nov 2017'
                         , [Dec 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Dec 2017'
                    FROM   #Temp y
                    WHERE  y.employeeId = x.employeeId
                    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) data
FROM   #Temp x
```

which works, but its performance is not great. In this sample it takes 25 seconds to do this but in my real dataset it takes a lot longer. It takes 1 second to return all the results from the #Temp table.
Is there anyway I can redesign my query here to improve the query time? I did try using a cursor to iterate through each employeeId and generating the json string that way, but it still sucks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Read "Performance Surprises and Assumptions : GROUP BY vs. DISTINCT" by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct)

Try to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` throws duplicates away **after** the resultset was created, thus calling your call to JSON more often than needed. `GROUP BY` should first reduce the set to distinct `employeeId` values and perform the JSON only once for each.

Cannot test it at the moment, but this should do the same, just faster:

```
SELECT x.employeeId
              , (   SELECT y.category
                         , y.subCategory
                         , y.productName
                         , [Jul 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Jul 2017'
                         , [Aug 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Aug 2017'
                         , [Sep 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Sep 2017'
                         , [Oct 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Oct 2017'
                         , [Nov 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Nov 2017'
                         , [Dec 2017] AS 'salesAmounts.Dec 2017'
                    FROM   #Temp y
                    WHERE  y.employeeId = x.employeeId
                    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) data
FROM   #Temp x
GROUP BY x.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Thank-you. I cannot believe I didn't think to try this. You're right, it ran in 1 second.

Comment: @Liv, glad to help you. Aaron Bertrand is right: *Performance Surprise* :-D